# Characteristic vector components expressed as polynomial in $A$ and $\lambda$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $\lambda$ is a simple root of $A$, a characteristic vector $x$ associated with $\lambda$ can always be taken to be a vector whose components are polynomials in $\lambda$ and the elements of $A$.
[Original problem description](http://books.google.com/books?id=sP8J4oqwlLkC&lpg=PP1&dq=richard%20bellman%20matrix&pg=PA37#v=onepage&q&f=false).

The problem suggests using the fact that if $\lambda$ is a simple root of $A$ then $|A_k-\lambda I|$ is nonzero for some $k$ where $A_k$ is a $(N-1)\times(N-1)$ matrix obtained by removing the $k$th row and column.

But before I figure out why that is relevant. Why doesn't something like row reduction on $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ using the minimal polynomial of the particular $\lambda$ in question for simplification work to find a characteristic vector $x$ whose components are polynomials in $\lambda$ and the elements of $A$? An eigenvector with rational components should be obtained but the denominators can be removed by multiplying by a common denominator. What obvious error am I missing?

Comment: There are several candidates for the "polynomial solutions", and you cannot know in advance which is going to be right. Similarly, you cannot know in advance which $|A_k-\lambda I|$ will be nonzero. So there is no unique solution, there is only a finite set of possible solutions. In each special case with specific numerical values you decide which candidates are right by looking whether certain quantities are nonzero. In algebraic geometry language, you need to decompose your algebraic variety into irreducible components.